# Product price comparison algorithm

Tags: algorithm, solr, sphinx

I am working on price comparison website, I am done with scraping all the stores product data (around 200+), Now I am facing the issue to show the data.

The problem is every store has its unique title of product like

For example **Google Nexus 5**

```
Nexus 5

Google Nexus 5

LG nexus 5

Google LG Nexus 5
```

or complicated example for **Canon 5D Mark III**

```
Canon EOS 5D Mark III 24-105mm Lens Kit (22 Megapixels, DSLR Camera, Black)

Canon EOS 5D MARK III + 24-105mm IS Lens

Canon EOS 5D Mark III DSLR Camera (Body Only)

Canon EOS 5D Mark III Kit (EF 24-105 F4L IS USM)

Canon DSLR Camera EOS 5D MARK III Kit with 22.3 MP and 24-105mm F4L
IS USM Lens

CANON 5D Mark III Body Digital Slr Camera
```

So on search I am not able to find out the exact matches based on title. What are the best way to scrape this data or any opensource framework which help me to show the best result based on model. Some says Dedupe Python Library can be used for that but I am not sure maybe there is a better solution

Comment: there is many different parts to it. Dedupe is probably good for initial clustering. But sphinx, may be good for finding similar results. Need to break it down. but honestly this is just somsthing you will need to experiment with, nobody can yell you best for your data.

Comment: Could also just take a leaf out of Google's book, and try to get part numbers from merchants to enable matches